# find() and delete() not working in laravel 9

Tags: laravel

find()
This is correct:

```
$user = Users::where('userid', '=', $id)->get();
        return redirect('/register/view');
```

This is Incorrect:

```
$user = Users::find($id);
        return redirect('/register/view');
```

delete()
This is Correct:

```
$user = Users::where('userid', '=', $id)->get();
        if(!is_null($user))
        {
            Users::where('userid', '=', $id)->delete();
        }
        return redirect('/register/view');
```

This is Incorrect:

```
$user = Users::where('userid', '=', $id)->get();
        if(!is_null($user))
        {
            $user->delete();
        }
        return redirect('/register/view');
```

Users Modedl:

```
class Users extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primarykey = 'userid';
}
```

Both codes are correct but not in my case. i don't know why. can anyone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: is ```userid``` an interger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a single record by `id` (or `userid` in your case), don't use `->get()`:

```
$user = User::where('userid', $id)->first();
// OR
$user = User::find($id);
```

When deleting, also don't use `->get()`. `is_null` on the result of `->get()` will always be `false`, since `->get()` returns a `Collection`, which isn't `null`.

```
$user = User::where('userid', $id)->delete();
// OR
$user = User::findOrFail($id)->delete();
```

Note: Your Model should be `User`, and the property to set the primary key in the Database is `primaryKey`, not `primarykey`:

```
class User extends Model {
  use HasFactory;
  protected $table = 'users';
  protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
}
```

You're misunderstanding and misusing Laravel a lot here. `->get()` should never be used for a single record, model names are singular, casing matters, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. Your answer is very helpful to me, and it also helps me to solve my problem

Comment: You're quite welcome! These are all things you have to eventually learn when using Laravel, and following the documentation and conventions set by Laravel is always a good idea. Cheers, and happy coding!